# Selenium Python - Waiting for <select> <options> to load before clicking

Tags: python, selenium

I have a nested selenium scraper that I am working on

```
schoolbox = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("clCampusSelectBox"))
schools = schoolbox.options
for index in range(0, len(schools) - 1):
    schoolbox.select_by_index(index)
    classtypebox = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("clDeptSelectBox"))
    classtypes = classtypebox.options
    for index in range(0, len(classtypes) - 1):
        classtypebox.select_by_index(index)
        classnumberbox = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("clCourseSelectBox"))
        classnumbers = classnumberbox.options
        for index in range(0, len(classnumbers) - 1):
            classnumberbox.select_by_index(index)
            classsectionbox = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("clSectionSelectBox"))
            classsections = classsectionbox.options
            for index in range(0, len(classsections) - 1):
                classsectionbox.select_by_index(index)
```

On every line where you see `foobar.select_by_index(index)` I am clicking an option in the select menu. Once I select that option a new select menu is loaded. Then I do a `Select(driver.find_element_by_id())` to get the select menu that was just loaded. I then try and get all the options in that menu with `foobar.options`. However, its not working.

I believe the problem is when I call `foobar.options` the options are not loaded yet. So I need to wait for the options to load. However, I have not figured out how to do this yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `driver.implicitly_wait(<seconds>)`?

Comment: I have and I believe it helps a bit but it's still not the best solution. Since it's not fullproof